# Fixed size array not fixed

Tags: c, arrays, random

I'm using SRand/Rand to generate an array of random numbers. The array size depends on a number the user is prompted to put in. Basically, if the user puts in a size of 9, the array should be 9 numbers. This array should then be populated using rand() with a parameter to keep the array values less than 18. The problem is, a random size array is generated sometimes. Maybe every 4th or 5th time I run the program the array might be 12-14 numbers.I can't see the problem with my code. I've included a snippet below. Anyone shed some light on it?

```
int main(void)
{
    int N;
    int i;

    printf("Please enter a number\n");
    scanf("%d", &N);

    srand (time(NULL));
    int numarray[N];  
    for(i=1; i<numarray[N]; i++)
    {
        numarray[i]=rand()%21;
        printf("%d\n", numarray[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ah I see! I been looking at it for so long I didn't see the obvious! Thanks a lot everyone

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
for(i=1; i<numarray[N]; i++)
```

You're looping over the wrong values.

- Arrays start at 0, not 1.
- You're stopping when the index is less than the value of `numarray[N]` (which is just a value in the array, and is undefined in this case since it's one after the end of the array).

I suspect you want to do this:

```
for(i = 0; i < N; i++)
```

Answer (score 4):

In this line of code:

```
for(i=1; i<numarray[N]; i++)
```

`numarray[N]` is an uninitialized variable, so it has an unknown value.
It could be zero, it could be 60,000.

The result is that your loop runs for an unknown number of iterations.

Answer (score 2):

Did you actually mean to have your for loop index terminate on numarray[N] instead of N?